# how to use listview which is inside a fragment with AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a `Fragment`, inside it there is a `ListView` . Now I am using `AsyncTask` to get some data from the internet with the help of `doInBackGround()` . Now i want to set that data with the help of `ArrayAdapter` in `onPostExecute()` to the ListView which is inside `Fragment`. How do I add data inside `ListView`, which is inside `Fragment`?

This is creating problem because my `Fragment` doesn't have a `Context`.

```
package com.example.the_hindu_news;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Async_list extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {

    private Internet_list ob_il;
    private String[] news;
    private String[] link;
    ListView ls;
    Base_class ob_bc;

    public Async_list(ListView ls, Base_class ob_bc) {
        this.ls = ls;
        this.ob_bc = ob_bc;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
        try {
            ob_il = new Internet_list();

            ob_il.parser();
            ob_il.parse_VIA_pull_parser();

            news = ob_il.return_news();
            link = ob_il.return_links();
        } catch (final Exception err) {
            Log.i("doInBackGround() : " + err.toString(), "tushar");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ob_bc,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, news);
            ls.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (final Exception err) {
            Log.i("onPostExecute() : " + err.toString(), "tushar");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you are using a fragment. Just use the getActivity() method in the fragment to get your context

Comment: Hi Neil thanks , but i am fetching some data from the internet & i want to set that data in that listView which is inside Fragment .... so that data will fetched after sometime , and by that i will get nullpointerException .

Comment: You should post your `AsyncTask`. Also, what is `Frame`? Also, also, if you're throwing an `Exception`, you should mention this in your OP and post the corresponding log.

Comment: Can you post your asynctask code?

Comment: aneal , sorry it is Fragment .

Comment: also please post your error stack. Where do you return your listview?

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface for exemple:

```
interface NetworkListener <T>{
    public void updateData(List<T>);
}
```

Your fragment implements this interface and update your list. Give the interface to your AsyncTask.